# Redefine mathbbm to print a colored output

Tags: renewcommand

I need `\mathbbm` to print a colored output.

I tried:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbm}

\let\oldmathbbm\mathbbm
\def\mathbbm#1#{\mathbbmaux{#1}}
\newcommand*\mathbbmaux[2]{{\color{red}\oldmathbbm#1{#2}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

$\mathbbm{i}$
${\mathbbm i}$

\end{document}
```

but the string `${\mathbbm i}$` returns an error. Where Am I wrong?

I need this trick to spot if authors used `\mathbbm`, directly in the pdf file. (I pass this strings to the `pdflatex` engine without modifying the source `.tex` file.)

Comment: The error comes because with `\def\mathbbm#1#{...}` you are defining `\mathbbm` so that it *must* find an opening brace. Why are you doing that *at all*?

Comment: @campa I updated my question giving an explanation of my purpose.

Comment: I understand that, but I still don't understand the reason for the brace trick `#1#{`.

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember... it's an old piece of code I've been using for a while, that never gave a problem until this case. Since I use it in a weird way I though `\renewcommand` didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use `renewcommand`:

```
%\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbm}

\let\oldmathbbm\mathbbm
\renewcommand\mathbbm[1]{\color{red}\oldmathbbm{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\mathbbm{i}$
${\mathbbm i}$ 
$\oldmathbbm{i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I do not recommend `bbm`, as its obsolete font format does not display correctly in a PDF. (And nobody prints DVIs on a laser printer any more.)

This lets you choose a more meaningful name, instead of redefining `\mathbbm` to mean something other than what someone reading your source would assume.  This has the happy side-effects of simplifying your code and solving your problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[bb=dsserif]{mathalpha}

\newcommand\mathredbb[1]{\textcolor{Red}{\mathbb{#1}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

$i \in \mathredbb{i}$,
$i \in {\mathredbb i}$

\end{document}
```

[image: dsserif sample]

Other nice things you can do with `mathalpha` are use a heavier blackboard bold as `\mathbbb`, select from an extensive list of math alphabets, and scale the font with the `bbscaled=` package opton.

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you could use the same code with `unicode-math` rather than `mathalpha`.

Comment: indeed I need this trick to spot  if authors used `mathbbm` directly in the pdf file. (I pass this strings to the `pdflatex` engine without modifying the source `.tex` file.)

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Ah! Classic XY problem! That makes more sense. Other methods: remove the `mathbbm` package, redefine `\mathbbm` to give an error message, do a search.